# CSS - Problem with visibility: hidden; on Dropmenu

Tags: html, css, html-lists, visibility

```css
ul.ulDropMenu{
z-index: 2;
}
ul.ulDropMenu li{
list-style: none;
position: relative;
}
ul.ulDropMenu li ul li a:hover{
    color: #ff003c;
}
ul.ulDropMenu li a{
display: block;
padding: 9px 14px;
}
ul.ulDropMenu li ul{
position: absolute;
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 4px;
padding: 8px;
}
nav ul li ul{
visibility: hidden;
display: block;
}
ul.ulDropMenu li:hover ul{
max-height: 290px;
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;      
}
ul.ulDropMenu li ul li{
width: 135px;
}

ul.ulDropMenu li ul li a{
padding: 6px 14px;
color: #2A2A2A;
} 

.navBar {
  background-color: #2A2A2A;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px 3px #8C8C8C;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px 3px #8C8C8C;
box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px 3px #8C8C8C;
padding-top: 3px;
}
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
nav ul a {
  color: #7f7f7f;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .4s ease;
  font-size: 18px;
}
nav ul li ul li a{
    font-size: 15px;
}
nav ul a:hover {
  color: #afafaf;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav #menu-toggle {
  display: none;
}
nav .label-toggle {
  display: none;
}
nav .wrapper {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  nav nav ul li ul li {
    color: #7f7f7f;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 0;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    width: 50%;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  nav li {
    color: #53354A;
    display: block;
    font-size: 19px;
  }
  nav #menu-toggle:checked ~ ul {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 62vh;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  nav .label-toggle {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #fff 20%, transparent 20%, transparent 40%, #fff 40%, #fff 60%, transparent 60%, transparent 80%, #fff 80%, #fff 100%);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    width: 35px;
  }
  nav .wrapper {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navBar">
  <nav class="wrapper">
    <a href=""><img width="215" height="85" src="https://www.dsgfs.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Test-Logo-250x60.png" alt=""></a>
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle" />
      <label for="menu-toggle" class="label-toggle"></label>
    <ul class="ulDropMenu">
      <li>
        <a href="">Menu 1</a>
      </li>     
        <li>
          <a href="#">Menu 2
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>         
          </a>
            <ul> 
              <li>
                <a href="">1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">2</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>                 
        </a>
        <ul>                     
          <li>
            <a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i> Facebook</a>
            <a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i> Twitter</a>
            <a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> Instagram</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</nav>
```

> Click on "Run code snipped" and on "full page" to see the snipped, and resize the screen under 992px.

The problem begins when i resize the screen under 992px. The `navbar` get bigger on the bottom, and the dropmenu don't open, i thought that it maybe was by the fault of the `display: block` but i don't think it is. I made some tests here and i realized that this problem was caused by this line:

```
nav ul {
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 0;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    width: 50%;
    visibility: hidden; //This line
  }
```

But if i take out the `visibility: hidden;` my collapisable menu will not work.

How can i fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You css is very messed up. You have unwanted space on navbar because `ul.ulDropMenu` is always visible and it has `padding-top: 15px` inherited from `.nav ul` and margins inherited from default browser settings.
I suggest you [read first about resets](https://css-tricks.com/reboot-resets-reasoning/)

```css
/* basic reset for all elements */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

ul.ulDropMenu{
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0; /* override padding set by '.nav ul' */
}
ul.ulDropMenu li{
list-style: none;
position: relative;
}
ul.ulDropMenu li ul li a:hover{
    color: #ff003c;
}
ul.ulDropMenu li a{
display: block;
padding: 9px 14px;
}
ul.ulDropMenu li ul{
position: absolute;
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 4px;
padding: 8px;
height: auto; /* override height set in '.nav ul' */
}
nav ul li ul{
visibility: hidden;
display: block;
}
ul.ulDropMenu li:hover ul{
max-height: 290px;
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
z-index: 1;
}
ul.ulDropMenu li ul li{
width: 135px;
}

ul.ulDropMenu li ul li a{
padding: 6px 14px;
color: #2A2A2A;
} 

.navBar {
  background-color: #2A2A2A;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px 3px #8C8C8C;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px 3px #8C8C8C;
box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px 3px #8C8C8C;
padding-top: 3px;
}
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
nav ul a {
  color: #7f7f7f;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .4s ease;
  font-size: 18px;
}
nav ul li ul li a{
    font-size: 15px;
}
nav ul a:hover {
  color: #afafaf;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav #menu-toggle {
  display: none;
}
nav .label-toggle {
  display: none;
}
nav .wrapper {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  nav nav ul li ul li {
    color: #7f7f7f;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 0;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    width: 50%;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  nav li {
    color: #53354A;
    display: block;
    font-size: 19px;
  }
  nav #menu-toggle:checked ~ ul {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 62vh;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  nav .label-toggle {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #fff 20%, transparent 20%, transparent 40%, #fff 40%, #fff 60%, transparent 60%, transparent 80%, #fff 80%, #fff 100%);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    width: 35px;
  }
  nav .wrapper {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navBar">
  <nav class="wrapper">
    <a href=""><img width="215" height="85" src="https://www.dsgfs.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Test-Logo-250x60.png" alt=""></a>
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle" />
      <label for="menu-toggle" class="label-toggle"></label>
    <ul class="ulDropMenu">
      <li>
        <a href="">Menu 1</a>
      </li>     
        <li>
          <a href="#">Menu 2
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>         
          </a>
            <ul> 
              <li>
                <a href="">1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">2</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>                 
        </a>
        <ul>                     
          <li>
            <a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i> Facebook</a>
            <a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i> Twitter</a>
            <a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> Instagram</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one thing, do you know how can i put the menu items inside the the navbar? As you see, i'm using the pseudo class on `nav #menu-toggle:checked ~ ul` and the `height: 35vh;`. The navbar's `height` gets different btw different screen sizes. I tryed to set the `height` with `px` but it don't solved, and i tryed to set the `height` to `100%`, but with the `percentage` i don't get the animation of the menu, when he collapse.

Comment: It's best to use javascript to toggle class for an element and just style that class.Here's simple example https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp

Comment: Actually i can't use javascript, i'm making a layout for a AMP-page. but thanks for the help!

Comment: @user236945896 then maybe this will help https://medialoot.com/blog/how-to-create-a-responsive-navigation-menu-using-only-css/